# Button disable timer

Tags: timer

please help me......

how to write a JavaScript code
I have a button and I want that someone click button after process button is disable even refresh the page and start timer for 24hrs and after 24hrs automatically enable.

Comment: some write this code

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: you can solve it

Answer (score 0):

problem is button disable properly but action ="abc" is not work anyone fix that problem.

```js
<script>
    const button = $('#submit');
    const pauseTime = 86400* 1000; // 24 hr

    let cache = retrieveDisableTime();
    let disabledTime;
    let currentTime;
    let interval;

    button.on('click', function(){
      disabledTime = + new Date();
      cache = {time: disabledTime};
      saveDisableTime(cache);
      button.prop("disabled", "disabled");
      setTimer();
    });

    if(shouldButtonBeOff()) {
        button.prop("disabled", "disabled");
        setTimer();
    }

    function shouldButtonBeOff() {
        disabledTime = cache ? cache.time : false;
        currentTime = + new Date();
        return disabledTime && disabledTime + pauseTime > currentTime;
    }

    function setTimer() {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            console.log('Not yet ready');

            if(!shouldButtonBeOff()) {
                console.log('READY');
                button.prop("disabled", false);
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    function saveDisableTime(obj) {
      localStorage.setItem('disableButton', JSON.stringify(obj));
    }

    function retrieveDisableTime() {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('disableButton'));
    }

</script>
```

```html
  <form style="width: fit-content;" action="abc" method="POST">
        <div class="card mx-2 " style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <input id="submit" class="button px-2" type="submit" name="SubmitButton">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).